# MongoDB REST API using LoopBack and StrongLoop return no results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to create REST API for MongoDB using LoopBack and StrongLoop.

Here is my project https://github.com/ackuser/slc-rest-api-mongodb-sample

It is not a relational database so I would need to use "*Creating models from unstructured data*" from what I understood

please see https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+models+from+unstructured+data

Until here it is ok, but if I create a model through StrongLoop Arc going to

http://127.0.0.1:3000/explorer

I am always getting an error related with the id (doesn't matter how I add the id to my model) and I cannot get any JSON due to problems cause of the id.

I was concerned about the problem, and what I have read is that you can fix it doing:

**By instance introspection using**

```
buildModelFromInstance()
```

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB1/Creating+models+by+instance+introspection

**or** with something like

```
var ds = app.dataSources.db;
MyModel = ds.createModel('mymodel', {
    _id: { type: ds.ObjectID, id: true }
});
```

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+models+from+unstructured+data

**or**

```
MyModel = ds.createModel('mymodel', {
    _id: { type: Number, id: true }
});
```

http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#datasource-prototype-buildmodelfrominstance
    https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/MongoDB+connector#MongoDBconnector-AboutMongoDB_idfield

**Note**: It is done programmatically, so being honest I don't understand the connection between the code I put before and StrongLoop Arc and how they 
are connected with each other to create the explorer API. In fact, I cannot get it working fine

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+models

Can anyone explain to me the logical steps to create & expose a MongoDB REST API with LoopBack and StrongLoop? Or at least, please tell me what I am doing wrong

I have created the issue on github so you can see all the process and the error

https://github.com/ackuser/slc-rest-api-mongodb-sample/issues/2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Updating your question with the error messages you get will make it much easier for others to help you

Comment: thanks, it was too long to explain here. Anyway, I just put an issue on github with some screenshots. https://github.com/ackuser/slc-rest-api-mongodb-sample/issues/2